# Android requestLocationUpdates when phone idle

Tags: android, geolocation

I'd like to track my Location every minute. For that I use a `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, pll);`

Here is the log when my phone is idle.

```
Date     Latitude             Longitude          Accuracy
07:45:35 51.362402459999996 - 6.2174867399999995 (75.0)
07:46:35 51.362402459999996 - 6.2174867399999995 (75.0)
07:47:35 51.362402459999996 - 6.2174867399999995 (75.0)
...
07:50:35 51.362402459999996 - 6.2174867399999995 (75.0) # I'm further than 75m away from my home at that time
```

I've indeed a new location every minute but it is exactly the same. Just the time is updated. The position is not updated (maybe normal when I don't move enough) but I find it strange that the coordinates are exactly the same. Also as I don't have wireless activated, it should locate me accordingly to the CellId (with an accuracy of ~1000m), here I still have an accuracy of 75.0. It seems, it is the last location recorded using wireless networks.

Any idea how can I record the real last location (even with low accuracy) ?

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    System.out.println(new Date(location.getTime())+" "
            +location.getLatitude()+" - "+location.getLongitude()+" ("+location.getAccuracy()+")");
    callback.addEntry(location);
}
```

Comment: did you checked your onLocationChanged() called at every 1 minutes?

Comment: The log line is printed in the onLocationChanged() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to force to compute the position using the LocationManager with the celltower only when there is no wireless connexion.
Maybe another way would be to use the method mentioned in the thread [Poor Man GPS](http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html) : manually compute the position knowing the CellId.

Pseudo code :

```
onLocationChanged(new_location)
    if isConnected()
       record(new_location)
    else
       cell_location = poorManGPS()
       record(cell_location)
    end
```

The problem is of course that I cannot query the cell-id database with no internet connection. I see several solutions :

- Store the current (and previous) cell id when I have internet and hope I'll stay in this one when I won't have internet
- Use the [cell id database](https://github.com/packetlss/android-locdump) on the phone (but I think root privileges needed)
- Store the cell id for further localization

Answer (score 0):

Hey use GPS_PROVIDER instead of NETWORK_PROVIDER as per below code

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, pll);
```

NETWORK_PROVIDER will give you only fix tower location and gps will give you exact changing location

Comment: But when the GPS is not enabled (most of the time), I don't receive anything.

Comment: you have to enable gps or your mobile should be in direct contact to ssatellite so that you can get gps locations. Only GPS can give you changing exact location...

Comment: My goal is not to have the best position estimation but how can I know my position now using what's available. If my phone is stolen, I want to be able to locate +/- where it is without having to send a sms to the thief "please turn on the gps and go outside".

Answer (score 0):

You have got nearest GSM tower coordinates.

Comment: With 75m of accuracy ? Only with GSM tower (which are in cache), Google Maps locate me usualy with an accuracy of 1000m). When I turn the wirless on, the location change (not much but is a bit different at each update) but the accuracy is the same.